# bxslider reload slider not working in another file

Tags: php, jquery, reload, bxslider

I just want to add a slide to bxslider dynamically, I did it successfully when i write code in one js file but my problem is I can not write bxslider reload code in one file.Have a look at my code then u will understand

My php file

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul id="slider" class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="images/pic1.jpeg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/pic2.jpeg" /></li>
</ul> 

<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

    $('#add').click(function(){
        var add_new = '<li><img src="images/pic3.jpeg" /></li>';
        console.log($('#slider'));
        console.log(slider);
        $('#slider').append(add_new);
        slider.reloadSlider();
    });
});
</script>
```

my js file

```
var slider;
$(document).ready(function(){
  slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

});
```

When I write that php jquery code in js file then it works perfect but currently it is not working.Can you tell me what is the problem with it while ' adds when i click on add button also if I console.log(slider) it is showing me their but not reloading it.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution myself :) I just declare variable with window.slider then it worked